# Why isn't Firebase library importing into my iOS Swift application?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

1) Firebase app was set up as per the instructions here:  firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

2) GoogleService-Info.plist has been included in my app directory as per the instructions

3) pod file was adequately updated with pods installed properly

3) Import Firebase is included on my AppDelegate.swift file as follows:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
  class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

let APP_ID = "AC51C6F9-D4AF-19F9-FF0E-3FF4363D1F00"
let SECRET_KEY = "82350646-04E6-65CD-FFE7-0B2CFAC49C00"
let VERSION_NUM = "v1"



var backendless = Backendless.sharedInstance()

var window: UIWindow?




func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    backendless.initApp(APP_ID, secret:SECRET_KEY, version:VERSION_NUM)



    FIRApp.configure()

    return true
}
```

---

Firebase is no autofilling when i type it in the AppDelegate file!  What can I possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

These things usually fixes it for me

1. iOS version in Xcode (e.g 9.2) is not the same as pod (deployment target)
2. restart Xcode
3. Build for running/testing
4. clean project
5. Objective-c framework

Comment: iOS version in Xcode (e.g 9.2) is not the same as pod

Comment: ^ how do I check this?

Comment: Open your pod file and check the line where it says iOS version and compare it to Xcode under General -> deployment -> deployment target

Comment: Thanks Joakim.  Objective-c framework ?  Sorry just not sure what this means exactly

Comment: If your framework is in objective-c you'll need to add a bridging header. But I don't think that is the case with Firebase